# SQLAlchemy One-to-Many relationship on single table inheritance - declarative

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Basically, I have this model, where I mapped in a single table a "BaseNode" class, and two subclasses. The point is that I need one of the subclasses, to have a one-to-many relationship with the other subclass.
So in sort, it is a relationship with another row of different class (subclass), but in the same table.
How do you think I could write it using declarative syntax?.

Note: Due to other relationships in my model, if it is possible, I really need to stick with single table inheritance.

```
class BaseNode(DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'base_node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    discriminator = Column('type', String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}

class NodeTypeA(BaseNode):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'NodeTypeA'}
    typeB_children = relationship('NodeTypeB', backref='parent_node')


class NodeTypeB(BaseNode):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'NodeTypeB'}
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('base_node.id'))
```

Using this code will throw:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: NodeTypeA.typeB_children and
>   back-reference NodeTypeB.parent_node are both of the same direction
>   . Did you mean to set remote_side on the
>   many-to-one side ?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was struggling through this myself earlier.  I was able to get this self-referential relationship working:

```
class Employee(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'employee'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
Employee.manager_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Employee.id))
Employee.manager = relationship(Employee, backref='subordinates',
    remote_side=Employee.id)
```

Note that the `manager` and `manager_id` are "monkey-patched" because you cannot make self-references within a class definition.

So in your example, I would guess this:

```
class NodeTypeA(BaseNode):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'NodeTypeA'}
    typeB_children = relationship('NodeTypeB', backref='parent_node',
        remote_side='NodeTypeB.parent_id')
```

**EDIT**:  Basically what your error is telling you is that the relationship and its backref are both identical.  So whatever rules that SA is applying to figure out what the table-level relationships are, they don't jive with the information you are providing.

I learned that simply saying `mycolumn=relationship(OtherTable)` in your declarative class will result in `mycolumn` being a list, assuming that SA can detect an unambiguous relationship.  So if you really want an object to have a link to its parent, rather than its children, you can define `parent=relationship(OtherTable, backref='children', remote_side=OtherTable.id)` in the child table.  That defines both directions of the parent-child relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!.
I tried, but I still get the same error.
How should I change the NodeTypeB class?.
In your code you define Employee.manager_id, and Employee.manager outside class definition. But in your propose to my code, you did not.
Sorry I think I am not getting it clear.

Regards.

Comment: The SQLAlchemy docs say it is OK to supply strings which get eval'd so you can get around the self-reference syntax error.  But I've never tried it.

Comment: In NodeTypeB your foreign key is to asset_base.  I guess that's a typo or you forgot to change the name before posting it.  I think if you change ForeignKey('asset_base.id') to ForeignKey(NodeTypeA.id) then it will be close to my working example.

Comment: The self-referential relationship can be defined without "monkey-patching" - use local or textual references: `manager_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(id))` and `manager = relationship("Employee", backref='subordinates', remote_side=id)`