# SQLAlchemy, one to one relationship on the same table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Location class. Locations can have default "bill to addresses" which are also locations. The fields that I am working with are `bill_to_id` and `bill_to` in class CustomerLocation. I have included the parent class a well for completeness. How can I set one location as the bill-to of another location? The relationship should be one-to-one (a location will only ever have one bill-to). No backref is needed.

TIA

```
class Location(DeclarativeBase,TimeUserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'

    location_id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    location_code = Column(Unicode(10))
    name = Column(Unicode(100))
    address_one = Column(Unicode(100))
    address_two = Column(Unicode(100))
    address_three = Column(Unicode(100))
    city = Column(Unicode(100))
    state_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('states.state_id'))
    state_relate = relation('State')
    zip_code = Column(Unicode(100))
    phone = Column(Unicode(100))
    fax = Column(Unicode(100))
    country_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('countries.country_id'))
    country_relate = relation('Country')
    contact = Column(Unicode(100))
    location_type = Column('type',Unicode(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on':location_type}

class CustomerLocation(Location):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'customer'}
    customer_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('customers.customer_id',
                                            use_alter=True,name='fk_customer_id'))
    customer = relation('Customer',
                        backref=backref('locations'),
                        primaryjoin='Customer.customer_id == CustomerLocation.customer_id')
    tbred_ship_code = Column(Unicode(6))
    tbred_bill_to = Column(Unicode(6))
    ship_method_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('ship_methods.ship_method_id'))
    ship_method = relation('ShipMethod',primaryjoin='ShipMethod.ship_method_id == CustomerLocation.ship_method_id')
    residential = Column(Boolean,default=False,nullable=False)
    free_shipping = Column(Boolean,default=False,nullable=False)
    collect = Column(Boolean,default=False,nullable=False)
    third_party = Column(Boolean,default=False,nullable=False)
    shipping_account = Column(Unicode(50))
    bill_to_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('locations.location_id'))
    bill_to = relation('CustomerLocation',remote_side=['locations.location_id'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782133/sqlalchemy-one-to-many-relationship-on-single-table-inheritance-declarative/6782238#6782238).  You can have self-referential relationships in declarative by declaring a self-referential foreign key in the table, and either "monkey-patching" the class just after it is declared or specifying the foreign column names as strings rather than class fields.  Example:

```
class Employee(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'employee'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
Employee.manager_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Employee.id))
Employee.manager = relationship(Employee, backref='subordinates',
    remote_side=Employee.id)
```

I've successfully used this technique before which gives you both directions of the parent-child tree relationship (where a single parent can have multiple child records).  If you omit the `backref` argument it may or may not work for you.  You could always simply choose to use only one direction of the relationship in your application.

Comment: I was unable to get it to work through strings, but using your explicit example post Employee declaration, did work. Thank you!